# How to make functions interact with class variables between eachother c++

Tags: c++, class, variables

I have been having trouble with a simple program that utilizes seperate file classes (i'm pretty new to them). Could you please help me figure out why it won't display the changed value?

main

```
 stats startout;

startout.beginning();
startout.start();
```

header

```
class stats
{
public:
void start();
void beginning();

//setter
void setHealth(int x){
    health = x;
    }
//getter
int getHealth(){
    return health;
    }
private:

int health;

};
```

implementation .cpp file

```
void stats::beginning(){
stats set;

set.setHealth(10);
}

void stats::start(){

stats stat;

cout << "Health: " << stat.getHealth() << endl;
}
```

It keeps displaying health as 0, which I assume is some sort of default since it is not being set as ten as described in my beginning() function. If anybody knows what the problem is or has suggestions on the best way to handle variables in classes and trading them between functions then please share your wisdom!

Comment: `stats set;` - what do you think that is doing? it's declaring a brand new variable. It's not referring to the object you are calling the method on. Why do you think the `this` keyword exists in the language? (But apparently you are entirely confused as to what an object is. You need to learn more about that first.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions start() and beginning() are still members of the class just like your getter and setter functions. That they're in a different .cpp doesn't mean you need new local instances of stats `set` and `stat` respectively, they still members of the instance declared as `startout` and will operate on it. You've made them operate on brand new instances.

So they should be defined as

```
void stats::beginning() {
  setHealth(10);
}

void stats::start() { 
  cout << "Health: " << getHealth() << endl;
}
```